# Как добавить такой плавный скролл?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

посмотрите пожалуйста этот сайт
ouiwill.com , подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно сделать такой плавный скрол. Я столько плагинов перепробовал но здесь прямо очень круто смотрится
Да я знаю что тут используется паралакс секции, но мне нравиться именно скролл. По коду насколько можно видеть идет эффект через translateY + transition

Comment: Ну у них на сайте обычный скролл, но плавно двигаются остальные блоки.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде так у них (но это не точно).

```js
var y = 0, Y = 0, ease = 0.04, s = 70

onwheel = (e) => {
  dir = e.deltaY < 0 ? -1 : 1
  Y += s * dir
  Y = Math.min(Math.max(0, Y), innerHeight * 2)
}

function update() {
  y += (Y - y) * ease

  one.style.transform = `translateY(-${y}px)`
  two.style.transform = `translateY(-${innerHeight}px)`
  three.style.transform = `translateY(-${y}px)`

  requestAnimationFrame(update)
}

update()
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.fake-scroll {
  height: 300vh;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.container>div {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: black;
}

.container>div:nth-child(1) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.container>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/800);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fake-scroll"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="one"></div>
    <div id="two"></div>
    <div id="three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: плюс влепил -но теперь за скроллбар не работает

Comment: @MaximLensky потом посмотрю